# Android Application gets closed immediately after opening in Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am new to android and trying to creating a simple android application. I am creating that android application in Visual Studio 2017 and Xamarin.

In that application, I have added a listview, where on click of an item of listview it opens up a new activity. When I clean and build the application it succeeded.

I archived that application and tried to test on my mobile. It opens and gets closed immediately.

Below is the code for reference:-

activity_main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <ImageView
        android:background="@drawable/done"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150px"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.cs

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Content;
using System;

namespace IH_Main
{
    [Activity(Label = "MyApplication", Theme = "@android:style/Theme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        string[] tool_array = {"Name1","Name2","Name3" };
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            //Adding items in the list view using Array adapter
            //Created an ArrayAdapter to store the list into Adapter so that we can set list string onto the list view.
            ArrayAdapter<string>tools_list = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this,Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1,Android.Resource.Id.Text1,tool_array);

            //Creating listview instance.
            ListView listView = (ListView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.listView1);

            //Setting adapter values to the listview.
            listView.SetAdapter(tools_list);

            listView.ItemClick += listView_ItemClick;
        }

        private void listView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, e.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
            Intent i = new Intent(this,typeof(info_display));
            i.PutExtra("Tool_Name", e.ToString());
            StartActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Layout1.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <ImageView
        android:background="@drawable/done"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150px"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    <TextView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tool_title"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Info_display.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace IH_Main
{
    [Activity(Label = "info_display")]
    public class info_display : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your application here
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout1);
            TextView t1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tool_title);
            string tool_name = Intent.GetStringExtra("Tool_Name");
            t1.Text = tool_name;

        }
    }
}
```

While performing "Build", I get the following warning.

> 'AbsListView.SetAdapter(IListAdapter)' is obsolete: 'Please use the
>   Adapter property setter'

on the following line in MainActivity.cs

> listView.SetAdapter(tools_list);

What could be the possible reason for that behavior?
Any help would be appreciable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue in my case by changing the syntax of the following line:

```
listView.SetAdapter(tools_list);
```

to :

```
listView.Adapter = tools_list;
```